# Preserving the transaction of an IntegrationFlow when handling errors

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Consider the following IntegrationFlow:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mongoFlow(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(MongoDb.inboundChannelAdapter(mongoTemplate, "{'status' : 'READY'}")
                    .update(Update.update("status", "DONE"))
                    .collectionName("test").entityClass(Document.class), 
                        p -> p.poller(pm -> pm.fixedDelay(1000L).transactional()))
                .split()
                .handle((GenericHandler<Document>) (p, h) -> {
                    if(p.get("message").toString().contains("james"))
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no talking to james allowed");
                    // process message
                    return p;
                }).nullChannel();
    }
```

This gets a lock on the record and sets it to DONE.  If the flow succeeds the transactions is committed otherwise it rolls back.  In this case a message to my co-worker James will never succeed, so the message fails over and over again.  My first attempt was to use an error channel to mark it FAILED after three failed attempts.

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mongoFlow(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(MongoDb.inboundChannelAdapter(mongoTemplate, "{'status' : 'READY'}")
                    .update(Update.update("status", "DONE"))
                    .collectionName("test").entityClass(Document.class), 
                        p -> p.poller(pm -> pm.fixedDelay(1000L).transactional()))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.errorChannel("testError"))
                .split()
                .handle((GenericHandler<Document>) (p, h) -> {
                    if(p.get("message").toString().contains("james"))
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no talking to james allowed");
                    // process message
                    return p;
                }).nullChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorFlow(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("testError")
                .transform(MessageHandlingException::getFailedMessage)
                .handle((GenericHandler<Document>)(p, h) -> 
                    p.append("fails", p.getInteger("fails", 0) + 1)
                        .append("status", p.getInteger("fails") > 2 ? "FAILED" : "READY"))
                .handle(MongoDb.outboundGateway(mongoTemplate).collectionName("test")
                  .entityClass(Document.class)
                    .collectionCallback((c, m) -> 
                        c.findOneAndUpdate(Filters.eq("uuid", 
                                               ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("uuid")), 
                            Updates.combine(
                                Updates.set("status", ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("status")),
                                Updates.set("fails",  ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("fails" ))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .nullChannel();
    }
```

This works but the transaction is terminated when the message leaves the `mongoFlow` and is sent to the `testError` channel.  I want to update the record to either increment the failure count with a status of READY or set the status to FAILED and then commit.

My next attempt was to use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
    @Bean
    public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice handleErrorAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
        advice.setOnSuccessExpression(new FunctionExpression<GenericMessage<Document>> (
            gm -> gm.getPayload().append("status", "DONE")
        ));
        advice.setOnFailureExpression(new FunctionExpression<GenericMessage<Document>> (
            gm -> gm.getPayload().append("fails", p.getInteger("fails", 0) + 1)
                        .append("status", p.getInteger("fails") > 2 ? "FAILED" : "READY")
        ));

        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mongoFlow(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(MongoDb.inboundChannelAdapter(mongoTemplate, "{'status' : 'READY'}")
                    .update(Update.update("status", "PROCESSING"))
                    .collectionName("test").entityClass(Document.class), 
                        p -> p.poller(pm -> pm.fixedDelay(1000L).transactional()))
                .split()
                .handle((GenericHandler<Document>) (p, h) -> {
                    if(p.get("message").toString().contains("james"))
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no talking to james allowed");
                    // process message
                    return p;
                }, e -> e.advice(handleErrorAdvice()))
              .handle(MongoDb.outboundGateway(mongoTemplate).collectionName("test")
                 .entityClass(Document.class)
                    .collectionCallback((c, m) -> 
                        c.findOneAndUpdate(Filters.eq("uuid", 
                                           ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("uuid")), 
                            Updates.combine(
                                Updates.set("status", ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("status")),
                                Updates.set("fails",  ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("fails" ))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .nullChannel();
    }
```

This updates the record within the same transaction and then saves it like I want.  But I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing things.  One odd thing about it that I don't really like is that I have to set the status to some intermediate value just for the sake of locking the record.  Then I need the advice to set the status accordingly before the flow uses the outbound gateway to save it.  I thought the error channel approach seemed more elegant but I'm not sure if it's possible to have the transaction boundary span both flows as long as the errorChannel is a DirectChannel.

Am I on the right track here or am I completely lost?

I should note that when testing the transactions, I had put some `Thread.sleep()` lines in there so I had time to try and steal the locked record.  I removed it from the post just to make it cleaner.

EDIT: Latest iteration using `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` combined with `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mongoFlow(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(MongoDb.inboundChannelAdapter(mongoTemplate, "{'status' : 'READY'}")
                    .collectionName("test").entityClass(Document.class)
                        .update(Update.update("status", "PROCESSING")), 
                        p -> p.poller(pm -> pm.fixedDelay(1000L).transactional()))
                .split()
                .handle((GenericHandler<Document>) (p, h) -> {
                    if(p.get("message").toString().contains("james"))
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no talking to james allowed");
                    return p;
                }, e -> e.advice(statusAdvice(), retryAdvice()))
                .log( m -> "\n------AFTER ADVICE------\n" + m.getPayload())
                .handle(MongoDb.outboundGateway(mongoTemplate).collectionName("test").entityClass(Document.class)
                    .collectionCallback((c, m) -> 
                        c.findOneAndUpdate(Filters.eq("uuid", ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("uuid")), 
                                            Updates.set("status", ((Document) m.getPayload()).get("status"))
                        )
                    )
                 )
                .nullChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        advice.setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate.builder()
            .maxAttempts(3)
            .exponentialBackoff(1000L, 2, 10000)
            .build());
        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice statusAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
        advice.setOnSuccessExpression(new FunctionExpression<GenericMessage<Document>>(gm -> {
            System.out.println("============================== SUCCESS ADVICE ============================");
            return gm.getPayload().append("status", "DONE");
        }));
        advice.setOnFailureExpression(new FunctionExpression<GenericMessage<Document>>(gm -> {
            System.out.println("============================== FAILURE ADVICE ============================");
            return gm.getPayload().append("status", "FAILED");
        }));

        return advice;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The error handling in the Polling Endpoint is done after transaction is rolled back. The transaction interceptor is applied to the `Callable<Message<?>> pollingTask` as an AOP advice. This one is called from a `pollForMessage()` like this:

```
private Runnable createPoller() {
    return () ->
            this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (this.maxMessagesPerPoll == 0) {
                        logger.info("Polling disabled while 'maxMessagesPerPoll == 0'");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
}
```

The error handling is done as a decoration on tasks scheduled to that `this.taskExecutor`.

Therefore to keep transaction and handle such a business error is not possible via `errorChannel` configuration.

You may consider to use a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` on your `handle()` to retry those business errors. This way the original transaction will be held and no new messages are going to be pulled from MongoDB.

You indeed might also need to combine it with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` as a first interceptor to handle errors already after all retries.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html

Comment: Thanks Artem.  I also see that the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` let's you define a recovery callback that executes if all retries have been exhausted and were not successful.  Would it be safe to simply have the recovery callback update the record as failed?  Or perhaps return an object that the next handler in the chain could use to handle failure?  My impression of this Advice seems that the answer would be "no".  And that the only purpose of a Retry advice is to avoid an error case (by retrying or recovering) and not to handle any errors.

Comment: edited original question with one more iteration of the code at the bottom using retry plus expression advice.  the retry advice simply retries 3 times then gives up.  the expression advice returns a result indicating success or failure which is used by the final output gateway status before committing.  i *think* this should all happen in the same txn.

Comment: Yes. That solution is correct according to you expectations description before. So, you indeed retry some time first, then you mark with respective status and move on to the next step. Yes, everything happens within the same transaction.